# draw9patch image doesn't get stretched correctly

Tags: android, nine-patch

i got an Image with following dimensions:

[image]

i convert it to a 9patch and mark following Areas as stretchable:

[image]

**this is what i get as result:**

[image]

**and this is how it should look like:** (From gimp, borders are translucent)

[image]

I put the 9patch into my `drawable-mdpi-folder`.(all the other drawable-folders are empty, so android can only pick that one!)

And i'm using a Nexus 5 768x1280 Screen Resolution.

Does somebody know what i'm doing wrong here? On the `draw-9-patch-tool`-preview located in the `/Android-sdk/Tools/draw-9-patch` it Looks good in both direction! (Stretching height, Stretching width).

Any help is appreciated.

**Updated:**
Original 9patch Picture

[image]

Comment: Does your filename contains ".9" string?

Comment: @Kai yes, the filename in the drawable-mdpi contains.9. But the line in the XML does not! See my XML line: `<item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_background</item>`. I add the Background to my edittext over a style.

Comment: `the line in the XML does not` It doesn't have to. Your 9 patch looks poorly designed. Are you sure the markers are **full black** (#000000) and **1px** wide and tall ad that they lay on the sides? Moreover, 9 patches are thought to **minimize** the graphical area. Your 9 patch looks way **too big**. If you shared the **real image** (not a screenshot from the draw9patch tool), I could spot out the mistakes.

Comment: @DerGolem If you say markers, you mean the 9patch markers for marking the area which can be stretched? If so, than you can see them in my question above this is directly out of the draw9patch-tool where i highlighted the marked Areas... i followed a tutorial on YouTube who did the same and it worked fine... don't know what i'm doing wrong but i will post the original 9patch. And i don't know why ma question gets downvoted didn't i try to provide all the Infos to get Support? dergolem, i should be saying sorry that i have not posted the perfect question..

Comment: Can't speak for the downvoter (not me). But, yes, the markers I mentioned are the ones used to define the 9 patch regions.

Comment: @DerGolem Ok, i've updated my question now you can clearly see the marked ares on the top and the left out of the unscaled original 9patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I optimized (96*96 px, 1.28 KB) your picture (685*322 px, 2.43 KB):

[image]

Basically, I cut off the exceeding parts, leaving just the essentials.
Then I added the **1 px** border.

On the upper and left sides I set the repeating area markers (horizontal and vertiaca, respectively).
On the lower and right sides I set the padding area markers (horizontal and vertiaca, respectively).

Note: the borders are **black** (#ffffff). And there's nothing else on the borders.

I gave the file the name rect_round_wht**.9.png** (mind the double extension).

This is the preview in the draw9patch tool:

[image]

The violet area is wher the text will be rendered.

As usual, make sure the extension is **.9.png**, not just **.png**.

Here is a nice tutorial on 9 patches: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: Thank you, i will read trough the tutorial but can't you provide a Little Explanation what you did? And what i did wrong? Would be nice..

Comment: I edited my answer. Adding a **poor** synthesis of what you'll find in the **great tutorial** I linked.